# Footprint of integration applications in Mule ESB

Tags: mule

I want to have a shared Mule ESB server where I'm going to deploy many integration apps. Most of them are similar but with different parameters and they have to be independent from each other.

I want to know how many integration applications can a deploy in one Mule ESB container. I'm not so worried about CPU usage because that's easily balanced having many servers, but I'm more concerned about memory usage or any other Mule ESB limitation.

I understand that memory usage of integration apps depends on the integration you are deploying to Mule ESB, but would be good to understand the overhead of deploying of a new app. Does it load all Mule classes again? Does it reuse what's already loaded? All applications are active all the time consuming memory or they are put to sleep while they are inactive?

For example, deploying Mule ESB without apps consumes 100MB, then deploying one app consumes 120MB, can I conclude that each integration application of the same type will consume 20MB?

Comment: Did you get any further on this situation? I am in the same boat looking for some advice.

Comment: Sorry about the late reply. At the end we decided to use a different approach to achieve isolation where we deploy apps in Docker containers inside a cluster of machines managed by Kubernetes.